# PHP exec expect script with SCP

Tags: php, ssh, cygwin, expect, scp

I have a PHP script at C:\WampServer\www\dnsmasq\php\dnsmasq.php:

```
function uploadConfig() {
    exec('C:\cygwin64\bin\expect -f /home/Dave/bin/scp.expect asdf', $output, $exitCode);
    print_r($output);
    print($exitCode);
}
```

Which calls a script at /home/Dave/bin/scp.expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set password [lindex $argv 0]

spawn /usr/bin/scp /home/Dave/bin/test root@192.168.1.1:/etc/test

expect {
    -re ".*yes.*no.*" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*password.*" {
        exp_send "$password\r"
    }
}

interact
```

The file to upload contains one line:

```
Testing
```

Running the uploadConfig function results in the following output on the page:

```
Array ( [0] => spawn /usr/bin/scp /home/Dave/bin/test root@192.168.1.1:/etc/test [1] => root@192.168.1.1's password: ) 0
```

The file appears on the server at /etc/test but it is blank, i.e. it doesn't contain the word "Testing".

I can run the expect script inside a cygwin shell and it uploads the file with the content:

```
$ expect -f /home/Dave/bin/scp.expect asdf
```

I'm not sure where the failure point is when I try to do this from PHP.

Comment: Try replacing `interact` with `expect eof`. While you're developing an expect script, add `exp_internal 1` before spawning.

Comment: That's really helpful! I had no idea about the exp_internal option, which means I was getting zero debugging information. The -d parameter does the same thing apparently. I'll try this as soon as I can.

Comment: @glennjackman `expect eof` did the trick. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `interact` when you want to, guess what, interact with the spawned application interactively.

If you want to spawn a program, send some data to it, and wait for it to finish, use `expect eof` instead.